# Dataframe is and object rather than a normal dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I created a dataframe from the sum of another dataframe rows, but the result is an object, so I can't do any calculation with it. I'm using pandas in Jupyter.

Here is my code:

```
df_sum = pd.DataFrame()
df_sum['Suma'] = df_consumption.groupby(['Country','Category'])['Mult'].agg('sum')
df_sum['Suma']

Out: COICOP level 2 - code
    Country      COICOP level 2 - code
Afghanistan...
Name: Mult, dtype: object
```

Any ideas about how to create a normal dataframe?

Thanks!!

Comment: you're mistaken, you're calling `df_sum['Suma']` which will pretty print the `Series`, the `dtype` is `object` as it contains `string` `dtype`, this is expected output

Comment: I know, I was showing the output type, to show that I don't want that.

Comment: Well then your question is unclear, you need to post raw data, code to reproduce your df, your attempts and the desired result

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert it to a dataframe object, you can try using df_sum = df_sum.to_frame()